# Customizing COD of WooCommerce on Checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I am working on an ecommerce website build on Wordpress and WooCommerce. The thing that I am struggling with is to integrate the Dial2Verify within the COD option on the checkout page. I am not aware of php and hence don't understand how to integrate the same within WooCommerce.

The thing I want to achieve is, when a customer selects COD (Cash On Delivery) Radio button on checkout page, a simple form preceeded by a brief instruction on how to use the form. The form will have only one field which will ask customer's mobile number. Upon form submission the Dial2Verify API V2 will be triggered and will wait for customer to dial the phone number prompted on the screen for verification.

The documentation for Dial2Verify API can be found here: https://www.kb.dial2verify.in/questions/30/Dial2Verify+Universal+Plug-N-Play+Plugin

https://www.kb.dial2verify.in/questions/47/API+Syntax+Overview

Comment: Show us what you have so far. No we are not gonna read the documentation, No we are not gonna write the code for you. Yes we will help if you have a problem with your code.

Comment: I don't know how to code in php. I want to integrate Dial2Verify since I don't want any fake orders to be placed on the website. The url of the website is big snip dot com. I tried doing it but don't know how to create a form in php as the API requires two arguments.

Comment: I can change my question a bit. I want to add a php form within the WooCommerce COD template (class-wc-gateway-cod.php). I want to add a field that will ask customer their mobile number and hit Submit. Also want to know if it works if I place javascript within php code.